# Merge three ByteArrays together and then split resulting ByteArrays

Tags: java

I have a `ByteArray` value as `avroBinaryValue` , `Schema Id` value as `short` `schemaId` and `Last Modified Date` value as `lastModifiedDate` in `long`.

```
short schemaId = 32767;
long lastModifiedDate = "1379811105109L";
byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.toByteArray();
```

Now, I will write `schemaId` , `lastModifiedDate` and `avroBinaryValue` together into a single `ByteArray` and then deserialize that final `ByteArray` value to extract `schemaId` , `lastModifiedDate` and `avroBinaryValue` from it.

Below is the code, I have got so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String os = "whatever os is";
    byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.getBytes();

    long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;
    short schemaId = 32767;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOsTest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream outTest = new DataOutputStream(byteOsTest);
    outTest.writeShort(schemaId); // first write schemaId
    outTest.writeLong(lastModifiedDate); // second lastModifiedDate
    outTest.writeInt(avroBinaryValue.length); // then attributeLength
    outTest.write(avroBinaryValue); // then its value

    byte[] allWrittenBytesTest = byteOsTest.toByteArray();

    DataInputStream inTest = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allWrittenBytesTest));

    short schemaIdTest = inTest.readShort();

    long lastModifiedDateTest = inTest.readLong();

    int sizeAvroTest = inTest.readInt();
    byte[] avroBinaryValue1 = new byte[sizeAvroTest];
    inTest.read(avroBinaryValue1, 0, sizeAvroTest);


    System.out.println(schemaIdTest);
    System.out.println(lastModifiedDateTest);
    System.out.println(new String(avroBinaryValue1));

    writeFile(allWrittenBytesTest);
}
```

I am trying to see whether there is any efficient way of doing this in Java or this is the only correct way of doing it in Java?

The way I am serializing all the three ByteArrays into one ByteArray and the way I am deserializing the resulting ByteArrays to extract the `schemaId`, `lastModifiedDate`, `avroBinaryValue` looks correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it is fine, however it seems like a better idea to just put all of the data you want to serialize into a `Serializable` object and then just serialize that automatically. For example you could do something like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
  String os = "whatever os is";
  long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;
  short schemaId = 32767;
  Thing myData = new Thing(os, lastModifiedDate, schemaId);

  ByteArrayOutputStream byteOsTest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream outTest = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOsTest);
  outTest.writeObject(myData);

  byte[] allWrittenBytesTest = byteOsTest.toByteArray();

  ObjectInputStream inTest = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
      allWrittenBytesTest));
  Thing myDataTest = (Thing) inTest.readObject();

  short schemaIdTest = myDataTest.getSchemaId();
  long lastModifiedDateTest = myDataTest.getLastModifiedDate();
  String avro = myDataTest.getAvro();

  System.out.println(schemaIdTest);
  System.out.println(lastModifiedDateTest);
  System.out.println(avro);

  writeFile(allWrittenBytesTest);
}

// in its own java file
public final class Thing implements Serializable {

  private final String avro;

  private final long lastModifiedDate;

  private final short schemaId;

  public Thing(String avro, long lastModifiedDate, short schemaId) {
    this.avro = avro;
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    this.schemaId = schemaId;
  }

  public String getAvro() {
    return avro;
  }

  public long getLastModifiedDate() {
    return lastModifiedDate;
  }

  public short getSchemaId() {
    return schemaId;
  }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with using Java serialization is that it wouldn't contain a "pure" representation - it would also contain the class, field, and serial version information. But I agree it's a good method if you just want to transport that data from Java-Java.You could implement `Externalizable`, though and achieve a pure data representation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing them to a byte array first, why not just write them directly to the file?

```
public void writeInfo(final OutputStream fileStream) throws IOException {
  final DataOutputStream data = new DataOutputStream(fileStream);
  data.writeShort(schemaId);
  data.writeLong(lastModifiedDate);
  data.writeInt(avroBinary.length);
  data.write(avroBinaryValue);
  data.flush();
  // if it's okay to close the underlying stream:
  data.close();
}
```

Of course, the method *names* the stream a `fileStream`, but really it's just an untyped `OutputStream` (to write directly to a file pass in a `FileOutputStream`). This is also testable since you can still pass in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.